# Add substring_index upto 3 and add comma - MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that select 1st 3 words from a field and add to a column in  another table:

```
UPDATE `site`,`clients` 
SET `site`.`words` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`clients`.`name` , ' ', 3)
WHERE `clients`.`client_id`=`site`.`client_id`;
```

1st three words added successfully, but I need to make them comma separated.

How can I do this ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `REPLACE` will fix it.

```
UPDATE `site`,`clients` 
SET `site`.`words` = REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(`clients`.`name` , ' ', 3)," ",",")
WHERE `clients`.`client_id`=`site`.`client_id`;
```

Comment: Thanks @Kay Nelson, let me check